# Select 9 elements from 3 arrays in PHP

Tags: php, arrays

As part of an autocomplete AJAX script I am writing, I would like to pull a total of 9 results from three sets of results.

Each result type has an array which holds a maximum of 9 results for that type. There are a total of three result type arrays as follows:

```
$places;
$venues;
$types;
```

The autosuggest should only include a maximum of 9 results of any type. So, if we take the lenght of each array as follows:

```
$places = 9;
$venues = 9;
$types = 9;
```

The result array should include 3 results from `$places`, 3 results from `$venues` and 3 results from `$types`.

However, if the counts instead look like this:

```
$places = 1;
$venues = 8;
$types = 1;
```

The result array should included 1 result from `$places`, 7 results from `$venues` and 1 result from `$types`.

I can't for the life of me figure out the most efficient logic to handle this. I tried writing each instance in an `if() else if()` block, but that really doesn't seem very efficient. For example:

```
$numPlaces = count($places);
$numVenues = count($venues);
$numTypes  = count($types);
$total = $numPlaces + $numVenues + $numTypes;

$results = array();

if( $total <= $maxResults )
{
    foreach( return_x_items( $places, min(3, $numPlaces) ) as $item ) { $results[] = $item; }
    foreach( return_x_items( $venues, min(3, $numVenues) ) as $item ) { $results[] = $item; }
    foreach( return_x_items( $types , min(3, $numTypes ) ) as $item ) { $results[] = $item; }
}
else
{
    $remaining = 9;

    if( $numPlaces > $maxOfType && $numVenues > $maxOfType && $numTypes > $maxOfType )
    {
        foreach( return_x_items( $places, 3 ) as $item ) { $results[] = $item; }
        foreach( return_x_items( $venues, 3 ) as $item ) { $results[] = $item; }
        foreach( return_x_items( $types , 3 ) as $item ) { $results[] = $item; }
    }
    elseif( $numPlaces > $maxOfType && $numVenues > $maxOfType && $numTypes < $maxOfType )
    {
        foreach( return_x_items( $places, 3 ) as $item ) { $results[] = $item; }
        foreach( return_x_items( $venues, ($maxResults - (3 + $numTypes) ) ) as $item ) { $results[] = $item; }
        foreach( return_x_items( $types , $numTypes ) as $item ) { $results[] = $item; }
    }
    elseif ( $numPlaces > $maxOfType && $numVenues > $maxOfType && $numTypes < $maxOfType )
    {

    }
}
```

Can anyone suggest a method to achieve what I'm trying to do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Very roughly done as I didn't have much time, but the logic might be able to help you, I'd probably approach it like this:

```
// Result types
$places = ['place'];
$venues = ['venue','venue','venue','venue','venue','venue','venue','venue','venue','venue','venue','venue','venue','venue','venue','venue','venue','venue',];
$type = ['type'];

// Place them in a common array
$result_types = [
    $places,$venues,$type
];

// Sort by smallest to largest
usort($result_types, 'sort_by_size');

function sort_by_size($a, $b){
    return count($a) - count($b);
}

$result_count = 9; // We want to have a max total of 9 results
$return = [];
for ($i = 0; $i < $result_count; $i++) { // Regardless of the number of each result types, loop through it 9 times
    foreach ($result_types as &$types) { // Loop through each result type in the order we specified earlier
        foreach ($types as $key => $value) { // Loop through the type within each
            $return[] = $value; // Take the first value
            unset($types[$key]); // Remove it so we don't use it again

            if (count($return) < $result_count) {
                break; // Got a result, now break out and proceed to the next result type
            } else {
                break(3); // We've reached the limit, break out of everything
            }
        }
    }
}
```

So in this case, we should have 1 place, 1 type, and 7 venues

```
print_r($return);
Array ( [0] => place [1] => type [2] => venue [3] => venue [4] => venue [5] => venue [6] => venue [7] => venue [8] => venue )
```

If we tried something like this:

```
$places = ['place','place','place','place'];
$venues = ['venue','venue','venue','venue','venue','venue','venue','venue','venue','venue','venue','venue','venue','venue','venue','venue','venue','venue',];
$type = ['type'];
```

We should get 4 places, 4 venues, 1 type? Which we do

```
Array ( [0] => type [1] => place [2] => venue [3] => place [4] => venue [5] => place [6] => venue [7] => place [8] => venue )
```

And with this:

```
$places = ['place','place','place','place'];
$venues = ['venue','venue','venue','venue','venue','venue','venue','venue','venue','venue','venue','venue','venue','venue','venue','venue','venue','venue',];
$type = ['type','type','type','type'];
```

We should have 3 of each, which we do:

```
Array ( [0] => place [1] => type [2] => venue [3] => place [4] => type [5] => venue [6] => place [7] => type [8] => venue )
```

Done this way, it'll always try to have an equal amount of each result type you feed it. When it can't, it'll take extra from those that have more to fill up until it reaches your specified max amount.

Answer (score 1):

The algorithm I would apply is:

1. Iterate the containers and extract at most 1 item per container where possible
2. If enough elements (or none) have been extracted, you're done
3. Go to step 1

This would give the most balanced result for cases such as 1-8-4 (1-4-4).

Graphically it would look like this:

```
              round 1 | round 2 | round 3 | round 4 |
container 1 |    x    |         |         |         |
            |         |         |         |         |
container 2 |    x    |    x    |    x    |    x    |
            |         |         |         |         |
container 3 |    x    |    x    |    x    |    x    |
              -------   -------   -------   -------
extracted        3    +    2    +    2    +    2      = 9
```